# Detect if an uploaded image comes from a ACF field

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a ACF image field, and I need to process the images that are uploaded by this field. I know how to process an uploaded media, but I can't find the way to find out whether or not this media comes from a specific ACF field. None of the hooks involved in uploading the image seems to give this kind of information.

Hooks&filters that I've tried: [wp_generate_attachment_metadata](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_generate_attachment_metadata/), [add_attachment](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/add_attachment/), [acf/upload_prefilter](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-upload_prefilter/), [wp_handle_upload](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_handle_upload/)

So: is there a way to know if an uploading image comes from an specific ACF field?

Comment: Have you tried giving this field a unique name/id/data attribute you can check?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that none of those hooks give me information about the field, just info about the uploaded image.

Comment: I see, so I assume you have multiple instances of the same upload being called. Can you not simply point them to different endpoints? So have the ACF field in a form that goes to upload1.php and the others go to upload2.php ?

Comment: The field is associated to a custom post type, so it appears when a new post is created or modified, it's not a custom form but the edit post form.

Comment: I don;t believe there is a way to determine if a field is 'from ACF by the contents alone. I think you either need another way to pass additional info or split the process to make it more precise